# Error While trying to bundle APK in React Native - Cannot read property 'update' of undefined

Tags: android, react-native

Running the following command to build an APK for my react-native project:

```
./gradlew --info assembleRelease
```

In turn runs

```
node  ./node_modules/react-native/cli.js bundle --platform android --dev false --reset-cache --entry-file index.js --bundle-output /home/ayush/myProject/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle --assets-dest /home/ayush/myProject/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release --verbose
```

which throws error:

```
error Cannot read property 'update' of undefined
debug TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined
    at new Server (/home/ayush/myProject/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:675:29)
    at buildBundle (/home/ayush/myProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/bundle/buildBundle.js:91:18)
```

Versions:

```
Ubuntu 16.04/18.04
node 10.15.0
yarn version v1.16.0
react-native-cli: 2.0.1

"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.0",
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "0.59.9"
```

Any Idea how to fix this error?

`react-native run-android` runs my app properly via the bundler

Comment: what is your react-native-community cli version?

Comment: @SamithaNanayakkara react-native-cli: 2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

React native cli 2.0 and later versions are for react native 0.60.0 and later updates. Please check [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli#compatibility). Since you are using react native 0.59.9, you better downgrade your react native cli and try to build again.

As you suggestion, I'd say just downgrade to 1.9.4 version and try to run again. check [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/374) thread too.

Comment: I use react-native-cli 2.0, community cli version I'm not sure about.

Comment: Because of the lean core of react native, they removed several packages from React native and handed them over to react native community to maintain them separately from react native package itself. Async Storage and CLI are two of those removed packages. If you need any more help regarding those packages, you better install community versions and check whether that version works fine.

Comment: * not currently removed, but they provide warnings of using them and ask instead using those, use community versions.